# Requesting better explanation for expires headers

Tags: cache, http-headers, yslow

I have successfully implemented expires headers however, for several days I have been stumped by one thing. This article: http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-add-far-future-expires-headers-to-your-wordpress-site-1533 states

> Keep in mind that when you use expires header the files are cached in
>   the browser until it expires so do not use this on files that changes
>   frequently.

Other sites indicate the same in my reading. But this doesn't seem to be true. I have updated an image, using the same name, several times. Each time I update and refresh my browser, the new image (with the same name) displays. I understand from this article that the old image should display unless I use a new name.

Do you happen to know where the misunderstanding is?

I have verified that the image in question has expires headers set on it:

**Request Headers:**

```
Host               domain.com
User-Agent         Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.28) Gecko/20120306 Firefox/3.6.28 FirePHP/0.5
Accept             image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language    en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding    gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset     ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive         115
Connection         keep-alive
Referer            http://domain.com/index.php
Cookie             __utma=1.61479883.1332439113.1332783348.1332796726.4;     __utmz=1.1332439113.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);PHPSESSID=lv2hun9klt2nhrdkdbqt8abug7; __utmb=1.33.10.1332796726; __utmc=1; ck_authorized=true
x-insight          activate
If-Modified-Since  Mon, 26 Mar 2012 21:55:33 GMT
Cache-Control      max-age=0
```

**Response Headers:**

```
Date           Mon, 26 Mar 2012 22:06:50 GMT
Server         Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Connection     close
Expires        Wed, 25 Apr 2012 22:06:50 GMT
Cache-Control  max-age=2592000
```

**Relevant config (.htaccess):**

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable Expires Headers for this directory and sub directories that don't override it
    ExpiresActive on

    # Set default expiration for all files
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 24 hours"

    # Add Proper MIME-Type for Favicon
    AddType image/x-icon .ico

    # Set specific expriation by file type
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It might be useful to add the request (`GET /foo/bar.png`) and the response code (`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`) to the headers.

Comment: Can you post the relevant apache config?

Comment: @LukeR, I just added "Relevant config (.htaccess)" in my original post. I am still unsure of why caching seems to be ignored. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing keeping the cached image and using the cached image. The browser *keeps* the cached image, as configured. However, the browser will not use the cached image if it know it is not current. Revalidation and expiration are two different things.

Comment: How does the browser know the file in the cache is not the "current" file? Maybe a better question: How can I make the browser always load from cache? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Cache-Control max-age=2592000, public", so the browser would save the file.

Comment: What does that do exactly? Thanks. Is it because no max-age is set that I am experiencing this?

Comment: No, now the browser would revalidate each time a webpage loads. With public he wouldn't do that again. 2592000 is about a month I guess.

Comment: It would be nice if your answer linked to the appropriate documentation that explained the Cache-Control.

Comment: @cobra91, I introduced this into my .htaccess file however, the cache is still ignored. As a result, I removed this configuration from my .htaccess file. Thanks.